# Wix ChooseLanguageDialog on Setupstart

Tags: wix

has anyone an idea how to show an Chooselanguagedialog on the startup of my setup. Of course this dialog has to set the lanuage of the Setup (Yes, i use localization like !(loc.xxx) ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiX's built-in story is to build multiple MSI's for each localization.  If you instead want a single MSI you'll have to do some custom build automation to generate the language transforms and then embed them into a single MSI.   Finally you'll have to create a Setup.exe that prompts the user for which language they want to use and calls the MSI indicating which transform should be applied.

InstallShield does all of this out of the box.  Hopefully one day WiX will also.

Comment: Hm, a lot of work for something I expected as default. Well, maybe just an english setup ;)
Thanks for your knowledge once more :)